# How to configure the AWS SNS notification email subject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

We are using AWS SNS to send out email for Alarms .We receive the email with subject Newsletter/Marketing which we are trying to avoid.
Is there any way where we can configure the subject for SNS notification email in  AWS console??

Comment: How have you set up the alarms? Are they coming from AWS Cloudwatch or another source?

Comment: It comes from CloudWatch.

Comment: That's strange, our cloudwatch alarms are also configured to notify us using SNS and they arrive with a pretty constant subject template. for example - `ALARM: "Service error" in US East - N. Virginia`

Comment: How did you configure SNS? did you let the the cloudwatch create it or did you create it manually?

Comment: i created topic manually and added it to cloudwatch

Comment: I get like this [Newsletter / Marketing:] ALARM: "CPU-Utilization" in US   East - N. Virginia .Need to avoid the [Newsletter / Marketing:] from subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126692/discussion-between-althaf-and-yaron-idan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We receive the email with [the] subject [prefixed with] Newsletter/Marketing which we are trying to avoid

This does not sound like anything CloudWatch or SNS would be adding.

This sounds like something your email service or server is adding, after the mesage is received, in a misguided effort to be "helpful."

Examine the headers of the incoming mesage -- you may see evidence of this tampering.  Or Send the email to a mailbox on a different mail service, such as Gmail (which I assume you are not using, since my CloudWatch alarms do not show this), and examine what you see in the message.